# Middle header fixed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have three different headers.

I want the middle header to be fixed when i scroll down.
But if i change the middle header to fixed. I mess up header one and header two.

```
    <div class="row red">
      <h2>
        header one
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row blue">
      <h2>
        header two
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row red">
      <h2>
        header three
      </h2>

    </div>
```

Se fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/n01k9wtt/

Answer (score 0):

For a similar project I've used the Bootstrap class "navbar-fixed-top" then add padding-top to the 2nd and 3rd headings so that they don't overlap.